# Restricted permutations

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, permutation-test

I have some multivariate data and want to investigate the effect of some environmental gradient. I want to use capscale but I don´t know how to deal with the permutation scheme. I have made up some artificial data, with 20 sites along a gradient ("env"):

```
######### create some species data along a gradient
df <- structure(list(site = 1:20, 
                     sp1 = c(7L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                     sp2 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                     sp3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                     sp4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L), 
                     sp5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 8L), 
                     sp6 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                     sp7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                     sp8 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                     sp9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), 
                .Names = c("site", "sp1", "sp2", "sp3", "sp4", "sp5", "sp6", "sp7", "sp8", "sp9"), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

# add some linear responses
df$sp6 <- round(seq(1, 8, 7/19), digits = 2) # linear response
df$sp7 <- round(seq(1, 4, 3/19), digits = 2) # no so strong linear response
df$sp9 <- round(seq(1, 6, 5/19), digits = 2)

# gradient
df$env <- 1:20
```

If I sampled only once I would do something like this:

```
# db-RDA sampled at one time
require(vegan)
mod <- capscale(df[ ,-c(1, 10)] ~ env, data = df, distance = "bray")
anova(mod, by = "terms", step = 999)  # assess the "significance" of contraining variable
plot(mod)
```

Now imagine I sampled the same data trice, but in three different months:

```
# now we replate exactly the same data 2 more times 
repdf <- rbind(df, df, df)  
repdf$time <- rep(1:3, each = nrow(df))
repdf$site <- factor(repdf$site)
```

If I would use unrestricted permutations, then this won't capture the repeated measures and the p-values would be to low.

I could restrict the permutations within each sites (using strata = site in vegan), but this destroys only the temporal effect and yields to a p of 1 (because every permuation is the same):

```
repmod <- capscale(repdf[ ,-c(1, 11, 12)] ~ env, data = repdf, distance = "bray") # db-RDA
anova(repmod, by = "terms", strata = repdf$site, step = 999)
```

**My question:**
How should I restrict the permutations assessing the effect of the gradient taking this temporal correlation into account? What permutationscheme should I use?

**Some ideas:**
a) Permute the strata ( = sites), but not within the strata. This will destroy the env gradient, so the p-value is only determined by this.

b) Include "time" into the model (with interactions) and the run for time-effect a different permutation-scheme (permute within sites) than for env (permute sites, but not within sites).

I know about the permute-package and can incorporate it into permutest.cca, so my question is more theoretical.

Comment: Hmm, no one? I´ve added a bounty...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `env` is the variable you are interested in then we need to test the "effect" of this variable in terms of the variance explained by `env`. To do the test using a permutation we need to think about what is and isn't exchangeable under the Null hypothesis we are testing. In this case, the Null is no effect of `env` so under this the sites are freely exchangeable. Within `site`, the samples could be permuted but we should use a cyclic shift permutation rather than free permutation to preserve the autocorrelations. If the three time points are the same across all sites we might also wish to restrict the permutation so that the same permutation is used within all sites, thus preserving those correlations across `site`.

If `time` is a nuisance variable that you are not interested in, I would do a partial analysis, conditioning on `time` to remove it and look at the effect of `env`. To do this, include `+ Condition(time)` in the model formula.

```
> mod <- capscale(repdf[, -c(1,11:12)] ~ env + Condition(time), data = repdf)
> mod
Call: capscale(formula = repdf[, -c(1, 11:12)] ~ env +
Condition(time), data = repdf)

              Inertia Proportion Rank
Total         38.1148     1.0000     
Conditional    0.0000     0.0000    1
Constrained   16.5286     0.4337    1
Unconstrained 21.5862     0.5663    9
Inertia is mean squared Euclidean distance 

Eigenvalues for constrained axes:
 CAP1 
16.53 

Eigenvalues for unconstrained axes:
     MDS1      MDS2      MDS3      MDS4      MDS5      MDS6 
8.890e+00 7.312e+00 4.611e+00 4.793e-01 1.560e-01 1.370e-01 
     MDS7      MDS8      MDS9 
7.542e-06 5.719e-06 3.341e-06
```

To permute strata (here `site`), you can use **permute**. To shuffle just the strata as blocks of three samples, a suitable control object would be:

```
ctrl <- with(repdf, permControl(strata = site,
                                within = Within(type = "none"),
                                blocks = Blocks(type = "free")))
```

If you wanted to permute within `site` we would use this

```
ctrl <- with(repdf, permControl(strata = site,
                                within = Within(type = "series",
                                                constant = TRUE),
                                blocks = Blocks(type = "free")))
```

The `constant = TRUE` forces the same random cyclic shift to be applied across each `site`.

Even controlling for `time` (by conditioning on it in partial analysis) this only removes a linear effect of `time` so there could be some remaining autocorrelation in the residuals that are then used as the response data in the model testing the effect of `env`, hence the reason for using cyclic permutations even though we controlled for `time` in the model.

Something to be aware of is that when permuting strata, you have to have a balanced design, as here, with the same number of samples within each level of `strata`. The code that generates permutations from control objects does not enforce this as it is designed to be very general purpose. There is a function `permCheck()` that exists to check a given control object and balance is one of the checks performed. When we interface **permute** with **vegan** we will enforce balance using `permCheck()` but I don't think `permCheck()` works correctly in the current version of **permute**.

Of course, as we (well, I) haven't yet interfaced **permute** and **vegan** yet, you'll need to hack the `anova()` method to generate the relevant permutations.

---

[Apologies for not responding sooner despite being alerted to this by @chlalanne on Twitter - my reply has nothing to do with you awarding a bounty, I had a poorly 11-month-old asleep on my chest most of the past few days that curtailed my typing ;-)]

Comment: Thank you very much Gavin, for the clear and helpful response and also for the permute package! Looking forward when permute will be hooked up into vegan!