# How to account for repeated measurements and unequal sample sizes in RDA

Tags: r, pca, multivariate-analysis, ecology

I have a question going in the same direction as this one:
[Restricted Permutations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22211/restricted-permutations?newreg=5499de429f904a35bd27f7eff9037070)

However, I have a dataset of multiple Locations from which I have samples of sometimes 5 sometimes only 3 years. Not all locations were sampled in every year. I ended up having a dataset with observations e.g. several allel frequncies and a dataset with explanatory variables for every location. The second dataset contains information about soil characteristics, ownership of the fields and other agronomicaly relevant factors.

I want to use the second dataframe to explain the variance of my observations and came across RDA which seems appropriate. However, I don't know whether I can account for the repeated measures design in RDA or whether to use other statistical approaches in that regard.

I would like to control for the repeated measures design, while being aware of the missing data. I don't know whether this matters.

Second part of the question: I would like to do the analysis in `R`. Is the `vegan` package the best choice for this or are there alternative options? Also, do the observations need to be sorted by site within every year and do I need to put `Location` as a conditional factor? I know I can add conditional variables in RDA together with constrained variables but would it be sufficient to account for Year and Location as conditional variable?

I was approaching the problem with R and package vegan in the following way but is this the correct application?

```
rda("MyObservation"~"some-Constrained-Variables"+Condition("Location"+"Year"),"dataset")
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about appropriate syntax for using an R package. That would be off-topic here; please see advice in the Help Center on software-related questions.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are just asking if your code is right / how to correctly represent your situation in the code, or if you are asking about the statistical issues in this situation? If the latter, can you edit your Q to make its statistical aspects more prominent?

Comment: Actually the question is about both topics with more emphasis on the statistical aspects. I will clarify the question.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your Q. FWIW, I think it is acceptable to have the R code in your Q. You may get some R help along w/ your answer. (To potential answerers: if you want to see the original R code, you can see it in the [revision history](http://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/143316/revisions).)