# How to specify my permutation scheme?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, permutation-test, nested-data, vegan

I am studying the biofilm microbiome of mountain lakes and plan to use **PERMANOVA** with *adonis2* to assess the importance of some grouping variables (e.g. lakes with introduced fish vs. lakes without fish).
However, I am struggling to understand how I should specify my permutation scheme (while I read it was of paramount importance).

My study design looks like the following.

- I have samples from **10 lakes** from a mountain range, but 3 belong to Valley A, 3 to Valley B, and 4 to Valley C. Those valleys form geographical clusters.
- Each lake has been sampled **three times a year** (early-summer, mid-summer, late-summer) for 3 years.
- In some lakes, **fish have been introduced while other lakes remain fishless**. This is captured by the variable *fish* (0/1)  and this variable remains the same throughout the study period (in other words, a lake either with or without fish in this study).

```
# the environmental data:
metadata <- data.frame(sample=1:90,
                   season=gl(n=3, k=1, length=90, labels = c("early", "mid", "late")),
                   year=gl(3,3,90,c(2016, 2017, 2018)),
                   lake=gl(10, 9, labels = c("Lake 1","Lake 2","Lake 3","Lake 4","Lake 5","Lake 6","Lake 7","Lake 8","Lake 9","Lake 10")),
                   valley=c(gl(2,27, labels = c("Valley A","Valley B")),gl(1,36,labels = "Valley C")))
metadata$fish<-rep(0,90)
metadata$fish[data$lake%in%c("Lake 1", "Lake 5", "Lake 6", "Lake 7","Lake 8","Lake 9")] <- 1 #lakes with fish
metadata

# the (made-up) species data (let's say, for simplicity's sake, that I am interested in only 2 taxa in the biofilm microbiome)
Cyanobacteria <- with(data, as.numeric(lake)*5 + as.numeric(fish)*100) +rpois(90,500)
Diatoms <- with(data, as.numeric(lake)*5 - as.numeric(fish)*100) +rpois(90,200)
Y<-data.frame(Cyanobacteria, Diatoms)
```

Samples from the same lake are not independent of each other, nor are lakes from the same valley (lakes from a same vally tend to be more similar to each other in terms of chemical composition).
I am interested in two questions:

- The effect of time (**year** of sampling and **season** of sampling (early-, mid- or late summer) on the biofilm microbiome
- the impact of **fish presence** on the biofilms microbiome.

I want to make sure that PERMANOVA takes into account the nestedness and the time in my data. I read the argument `strata`, in the function `adonis` or `adonis2`, is now **deprecated**, and that the function `how` that we can pass in the argument `permutations` should be used.

I am just confused about I should set the function `how`. Ideally, I would like to do this kind of model `Y~fish + season*year`. But if too complex, I am mainly interested in the fish variable.
My guess would be

```
adonis2(Y ~ fish + season*year, data=metadata, perm= how(blocks = metadata$valley, plots = Plots(strata = metadata$lake), within = Within(type = "series"), nperm=9999), by="margin")
```

But I am really not sure of what I am doing, what blocks and what plots should be. However, if I am only interested in the fish variable, following what I read [elsewhere](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22211/restricted-permutations)

> To do the test using a permutation we need to think about what is and isn't exchangeable under the Null hypothesis we are testing.

In this case, the Null is no effect of fish presence so under this the sites are freely exchangeable. So I think I should only type that, right?

```
adonis2(Y ~ fish, data=metadata, perm= how(within = Within(type = "series"), nperm=9999))
```

Finally, in my real datasets, **some lakes have not been sampled three times a year**, but only once or twice. Is this a problem and, if yes, how should I deal with it?
Sorry, I am quite new to this field, any help would be really appreciated.